# How to display a 3D Model over a 2D maker (QRCode) using ARCore?

Tags: android, arcore

I'm doing tests with the sample Hello AR from the ARCore SDK 1.0. How can I display a 3D Model over a 2D maker, like a QRCode? Is there any class that detects the QRCode position at the ARCore API, or should I do that with an external lib?

At the sample application, the Android Robot (Andy) is shown when the surface is clicked. I wanna show Andy over the 2D marker.

Comment: Given that there are existing SDKs that do this like Vuforia, what have you done to break down the steps requires to achieve what your are trying to do ?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Vuforia is not free, I never used it. I still not know the firsts steps for detecting de QRCode, I will look for an external lib.

Comment: Detecting and getting the 3D orientation of a 2D marker is a image processing problem. Investigate OpenCV. I suspect you are trying to so something like: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html Demos like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlFUjM9nwi4 have been around for many years before ARCore. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As of now this feature is not supported. Hopefully they will do so in the future. You can't even control the camera's focus so i don't know how you could recognise anything other than the grid.

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/92